# Number of distinct sequences of fixed length which can be generated using a given set of numbers

Tags: algorithm, set, permutation, combinatorics, sequences

I am trying to find different sequences of fixed length which can be generated using the numbers from a given set (distinct elements) such that each element from set should appear in the sequence. Below is my logic:

eg. Let the set consists of S elements, and we have to generate sequences of length K (K >= S)

1) First we have to choose S places out of K and place each element from the set in random order. So, **C(K,S)*S!**

2) After that, remaining places can be filled from any values from the set. So, the factor

**(K-S)^S** should be multiplied.

So, overall result is

> C(K,S)*S!*((K-S)^S)

But, I am getting wrong answer. Please help.

PS: C(K,S) : No. of ways selecting S elements out of K elements (K>=S) irrespective of order. Also, ^ : power symbol i.e 2^3 = 8.

Here is my code in python:

```
# m is the no. of element to select from a set of n elements
# fact is a list containing factorial values i.e. fact[0] = 1, fact[3] = 6& so on. 
def ways(m,n):
    res = fact[n]/fact[n-m+1]*((n-m)**m)
    return res
```

Comment: Isn't this a math problem? What I mean is, is your formula wrong, or is the code implementing it wrong?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen My formula is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the number of surjective functions whose domain is a set of K elements (the K positions that we are filling out in the output sequence) and the image is a set of S elements (your input set). I think this should work:

```
    static int Count(int K, int S)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= S; i++)
        {
            sum += Pow(-1, (S-i)) * Fact(S) / (Fact(i) * Fact(S - i)) * Pow(i, K);
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

...where `Pow` and `Fact` are what you would expect.

Check out this [this math.se question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264799/calculating-the-total-number-of-surjective-functions).

**Here's why your approach won't work.** I didn't check the code, just your explanation of the logic behind it, but I'm pretty sure I understand what you're trying to do. Let's take for example K = 4, S = {7,8,9}. Let's examine the sequence 7,8,9,7. It is a unique sequence, but you can get to it by:

- Randomly choosing positions 1,2,3, filling them randomly with 7,8,9 (your step 1), then randomly choosing 7 for the remaining position 4 (your step 2).
- Randomly choosing positions 2,3,4, filling them randomly with 8,9,7 (your step 1), then randomly choosing 7 for the remaining position 1 (your step 2).

By your logic, you will count it both ways, even though it should be counted only once as the end result is the same. And so on...

Comment: What language is that? It looks like C#, though the question was asked in python.

Comment: Yes, it is C#. I am sure the poster will figure it out. I will post a simpler version.

Comment: @svinja I tried your approach, but its giving Wrong Answer. I implemented the entire logic in C# to make sure this is not a language problem. But, it always gives 0 as answer.
Here's the link to C# implementation, please have a look.
http://ideone.com/pF7u2k

Comment: @NewUser, the first parameter of function Count is K, the second is S, and K >= S. So I think you really want to call Count(5, 1), not Count(1, 5). This will return 1, which is correct (there is only 1 element, so the only solution is to repeat it 5 times).

Comment: @svinja It was a problem with python. Actually, pow(-1,2) i.e. -1**2  giving me -1. So, I was getting wrong answer. Thanks for the help.